# Selecting rows with minimal values [col1] of maximal values [col2] by id sql server

Tags: sql-server, max, distinct, multiple-columns, min

Sample data on
MAIN_TABLE:

```
+-----+--------+-------+
| ID  | HEIGHT | STOCK |
+-----+--------+-------+
| ID1 |    180 |   680 |
| ID1 |    170 |   680 |
| ID1 |    130 |   360 |
| ID2 |    250 |   420 |
| ID2 |    190 |   420 |
| ID2 |     70 |   120 |
| ... |   ...  |  ...  |
+-----+--------+-------+
```

I need to select distinct ID rows that have max STOCK with the min HEIGHT.

The desired result would be:

```
+-----+--------+-------+
| ID  | HEIGHT | STOCK |
+-----+--------+-------+
| ID1 |    170 |   680 |
| ID2 |    190 |   420 |
| ... |   ...  |  ...  |
+-----+--------+-------+
```

Query code, that i'm using to achieve it:

```
WITH MAX_STOCK (ID, maxstock) as
(
    select ID, max(STOCK) as maxstock
    from MAIN_TABLE
    group by ID
),
TABLE_STOCK (ID, HEIGHT, STOCK) AS
(
    select a.ID, a.HEIGHT, a.STOCK
    from MAIN_TABLE a join MAX_STOCK b
    on a.ID= b.ID and a.STOCK = b.maxstock
),
MIN_HEIGHT (ID, minheight) as
(
    select ID, min(HEIGHT) as minheight
    from TABLE_STOCK
    group by ID
),
TABLE_HEIGHT (ID, HEIGHT, STOCK) AS
(
    select a.ID, a.HEIGHT, a.STOCK
    from TABLE_STOCK a join MIN_HEIGHT b
    on a.ID= b.ID and a.HEIGHT = b.minheight
)
```

If I select any of tables MAX_STOCK, TABLE_STOCK, MIN_HEIGHT,

i have results in 1-2seconds time.

But when selecting TABLE_HEIGHT, which would be my desired result,

It is executing 6min+ with no answer on data with 600 rows

How should i write this query to have the result in reasonable time?

Comment: wouldn't the min height for ID1 be 130??

Comment: the stock has to be max at first, to calculate the min height

Comment: try the answer i posted

Comment: i do not see it :)

Comment: Disregard my previous message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use window functions to achieve this. Try following example.

```
create table #Main(
Id varchar(50),
HEIGHT int,
STOCK int
)

insert into #Main values('ID1',180,680),('ID1',170,680),('ID1',130,360 ),('ID2',250,420),('ID2',190,420),('ID2',70,120)

select * from (
select *,dense_rank() over(partition by Id order by STOCK desc,HEIGHT asc) as sira
from #Main
) k 
where sira=1
```